# Audio file in application doesn't stop on click, it starts playing again

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

So I put an audio file in my application and it's supposted play when I touch the button and stop when I touch it again.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    Button one = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonId);
    final MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();

    one.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(mp.isPlaying())
            {
                mp.stop();
            }

            try {
                mp.reset();
                AssetFileDescriptor afd;
                afd = getAssets().openFd("mosq.mp3");
                mp.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(),afd.getStartOffset(),afd.getLength());
                mp.prepare();
                mp.setLooping(true);
                mp.start();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


});
```

here is my code, this part:

```
if(mp.isPlaying())
        {
            mp.stop();
        }
```

didn't work for some reason.

Comment: You have a few other bugs too besides that, see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you put a `return` statement below `mp.stop()`.

From what I can understand the sound does stop but then it starts again because the next part of the code still gets executed

Comment: Or put the "start" logic in an "else" statement.

Comment: `if(mp.isPlaying())
                {
                    mp.stop();
                    return;
                }
`

worked fine, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As George D correctly pointed out, you start the media playing unconditionally, even if you just stopped it. You could use his solution or do something like:

```
if(mp.isPlaying())
        {
            mp.stop();
        }
        else {
          try {
            mp.reset();
            AssetFileDescriptor afd;
            afd = getAssets().openFd("mosq.mp3");
            mp.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(),afd.getStartOffset(),afd.getLength());
            mp.prepare();
            mp.setLooping(true);
            mp.start();
          } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
       }
```

This has several other potential bugs in it:
* I'm not sure if this is what you intended but the player won't ever pause, just stop and restart from the beginning. If you try to resume or play again it'll completely reload the audio file every time. At a minimum this is a waste of resources, plus it's likely not the expected behavior from a UI perspective.
* You don't want to define the MediaPlayer object as a local variable within the OnCreate method. The only reason this works at all is you have a memory leak (you never unsubscribe your event handler for the click); if you didn't have the memory leak the object would become eligible for garbage collection as soon as you completed the onCreate method and, as far as the framework was concerned, it would no longer exist.

Comment: `I'm not sure if this is what you intended but the player won't ever pause, just stop and restart from the beginning.` that's exactly what I wanted to do.

can you explain that memory leak please?